# Páginação com NodeJS com banco de dados MySQL

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js, react, paginação

Estou criando uma **API** para depois ser consumida no React. Nesta API terá uma rota(página) que vai listar os usuários do banco de dados.

Apliquei as regras e estou testando no insomnia, que por sinal está funcionando bem.

**Meu problema** e quando deixo o **parametro** da **url** vazio, **Exemplo: localhost/usuario/**.

Eu gostaria que quando deixasse vazio retorna-se a primeira página.

segue o código abaixo:

```
 if(results){
        const numero_registros = results.length; // Existe 37 registros no banco
        let  pagina_atual = req.params.page || 1;
        let total_paginas = Math.ceil(numero_registros/10); 


            let count = (pagina_atual*10)-10;

            connection.query(`SELECT * FROM usuarios_homos LIMIT 10 OFFSET ${count}`,(err,result,fields)=>{
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }else{
                    res.send(result);
                }

            });
```

Imagem do insomnia fazendo a exibindo a páginação:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Imagem do insomnia quando não passo o parametro
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**[PROBLEMA RESOLVIDO]**

```
 // Páginação
    if(results){
        const rows = results.length; // Existe 37 registros no banco
        let { page = 1 } = req.query; // passando argumento pela url >> usuarios?page=1
        let calc = Math.ceil(rows/10); // calc recebe a quantidade de páginas existentes

        if(page == ''){
            page = 1;
        }

            let count = (page*10)-10;

        const qtd = connection.query(`SELECT * FROM usuarios_homos LIMIT 10 OFFSET ${count}`,(err,result,fields)=>{
                if(err){
                    console.log(err);
                }else{
                    res.send(result);
                }

            });
```

**NAS ROTAS FICOU:**

```
router.get('/usuarios',queryController);
```

Comment: O que acontece quando você não passa a página por parâmetro na url?

Comment: Me retornar no insomnia 404 Not Found

Comment: Como você declarou a rota no node.js?

Comment: Coloquei >>      router.get( '/usuarios/:page', queryController);

Comment: Apesar da pergunta já ter sido resolvida, recomendo editá-la para adicionar o código da declaração da rota. Ele é importante e pode ajudar pessoas com o mesmo problema no futuro.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Olá, tudo bem?

Se entendi o que você deseja, é criar uma forma de quando o usuário acessar o `http://localhost:3010/usuarios` direcionar a paginação automaticamente para a página 1. Certo?

## *Conceituação:*

Para isso, vamos precisar desacoplar as suas rotas e utilizar uma padrão muito bacana conhecido como *middleware* (isso mesmo, é um programa que roda no meio de alguma coisa oferecendo um auxílio em alguma tarefa específica, como o tratamento de inputs por exemplo).

O nosso *middleware* neste caso, vai ser construído para tratar a url antes da listagem de usuários ser acessada.

## *Mão no código:*

Bom, vou configurar deste o zero um serviço express e você aproveita as partes que forem agregar ao seu caso, ok?

#### Criando o index.js, server.js ou app.js

```
// Porta do serviço.
const port = 4000;

// Importação do módulo express.
const express = require('express');

// Criação da instância do serviço.
const app = express();

// Importação das nossa rotas desacopladas (falaremos delas mais tarde).
const routes = require('./routes');

// Aqui podemos ver a primeira forma de um middleware.
// Com o método "use" eu digo ao serviço que ele deve executar as rotas importadas
// somente se houver um prefixo "/usuarios" na url.
app.use('/usuarios', routes);

// Inicialização do serviço.
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Running on ${port}...`));
```

#### Criando o routes.js

```
const express = require('express');

// Criação de uma instância de roteador (router) do express.
const router = express.Router();

// Aqui temos mais um middleware, e esse é a estrela do nosso negócio.
// É ele quem vai verificar a url e tratar para depois chamar nossa rota de paginação.
router.use((req, res, next) => {

  // Se a url for igual a uma "/" pura, reset ela para "/1".
  if (req.url === '/') {
    req.url = '/1';
  }

  // Chamo o nosso next, ele quem vai fazer a próxima rota na fila ser executada.
  next();
});

// E finalmente nossa rota de listagem com toda lógica complexa.
router.get('/:page', (req, res) => {
  const page = req.params.page;

  res.send(`Página = ${page}`);
});

// Exportação do router para que possamos usar ele no index.js
module.exports = router;
```

Comment: Muito bom, muito bom mesmo, mas fiz de uma outra forma usando req.query conforme o Rafael teria me indicado e finalmente consegui fazer a páginação.  Está forma que você usou vai ser muito útil pra mim até porque o código ficou bem limpo e fácil de entender. Vou salvar aqui como segunda opção.. obrigado cara!